# App crashes in release mode but works on debug mode

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary I trying to sort and present in a table view

when I build the app in debug mode it works fine but when I edit the scheme to release mode and run it locally it crashes without any information.

this is the code that is problematic where I am just trying to sort the menu's tasklist which is a dictionary but it crashing on when released.

```
var menu: Task!

let tableView = UITableView()

var sortedMenu:[(String, Double)]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TaskMenuTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TaskMenuTableViewCell")

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    menu = Task()

    let ordering = {

        (elem1:(key: String, val: Double), elem2:(key: String, val: Double))->Bool in
        if elem1.val != elem2.val {

            return elem1.val > elem2.val

        } else {

            return String(elem1.key) < String(elem2.key)
        }
    }

    sortedMenu = menu.taskList.sorted(by: ordering)

}
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my code since the sorting method works just fine event when I test it in a playground with various dictionaries. Anybody knows what is going on ? I am using swift 3 and xcode 8
thanks

Comment: If it crashes, then there's information relating to it in the debug navigator...

Comment: no specific information